# eZend_Json::encode or json_encode with special characters

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to encode an array which has special characters such as ñ.  When I do that it returns null. I tried to use this option in Zend:

```
Zend_Json::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder = true:
```

And it doesn't return null but, for example, in this string "something with ñ" return ""something with \u00f1"

And if a I use for json_encode, for example:

```
<?
$string = "something with ñ";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
$encode_json = json_encode($string) ;
print_r($encode_json);
?>
```

return is the same:

something with ñ

something with \u00f1

And if I use utf8_enconde(), return this character \u00c3 for ñ.

Some ideas to solve my problem? I need to save in the database at list words with ñ, if I can save another special character would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can encode Unicode Characters using json_encode() function as well

```
echo json_encode($yourdata, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

<sub>**Note:** This is only available PHP 5.4 onwards</sub>

Comment: I used  htmlentities($string, NULL, 'UTF-8'); with a simple string and it worked. I'll try with something more complex and post here my results.

Answer (score 0):

The `\u00f1` part is fine: it refers to Unicode codepoint 00F1: "small letter n with tilde."

Something decoding that JSON will understand that to mean the same thing as `ñ`.

Comment: And how can i traduce this character to ñ? this words is in the database and i have to retreive this in differents formats, such array, bidimensional arrays, etc..

Comment: Any JSON decoder will convert the `\u00f1` to an honest-to-goodness `ñ` character. With your sample code, if you ran the produced JSON through `json_decode`, you'd get the `ñ` back.